# (Rate of) Convergence in distribution and Laplace transform of random variables/stochastic processes

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, laplace-transform, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_t^n$ and $X_t$ be stochastic processes (with finite moments), and assume that for every $t>0$, $\lambda>0$ and bounded continuous function $\varphi$,
\begin{equation}
\int_0^te^{-\lambda s}E\varphi(X_s^n)d s\to\int_0^te^{-\lambda s}E\varphi(X_s)d s,\quad as \quad n\to\infty.
\end{equation}
Can we conclude that for every $t>0$,
$$
E\varphi(X_t^n)\to E\varphi(X_t),\quad as \quad n\to\infty ?
$$
A further question is that, if we know the rate of convergence, i.e., for a constant $C_0>0$,
$$
\bigg|\int_0^te^{-\lambda s}E\varphi(X_s^n)d s-\int_0^te^{-\lambda s}E\varphi(X_s)d s\bigg|\leq C_0\frac{1}{n},
$$
can we get
$$
\big|E\varphi(X_t^n)\to E\varphi(X_t)\big|\leq C_1\frac{1}{n} ?
$$
Thanks for your time and answer. Any comments or suggestions are welcome.